# Automorphisms of $C(\{1,...,n\})$

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, continuity

If I am not mistake, $C(\{1,...,n\})$ denotes all of the continuous functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\Bbb{C}$. I read somewhere that every automorphism on $C(\{1,...,n\})$ is a composition with a homeomorphism on $\{1,...,n\}$. My question is, a composition with a homeomorphism and what else? Also, what is meant by a homeomorphism from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\{1,...,n\}$? Would the symmetric group be all the homeomorphisms on $\{1,...,n\}$?

Let $T_U: M_n (\Bbb{C}) \to M_n(\Bbb{C})$ be defined by $T_U(X) = U^*XU$, where $U$ is an $n \times n$ unitary. Here is more context:

> Since $T_U$ is an automorphism of the $n \times n$ diagonal matrices and these are $*$-isomorphic to $C(\{1,...,n\})$, and since every automorphism on $C(\{1,...,n\})$ is composition with a homeomorphism on $\{1,...,n\}$, there is a unitary permutation matrix $P \in M_n(\Bbb{C})$ such that $T_U(D) = T_P(D)$ for every diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: The phrase "automorphisms on $C(\{1, \ldots, n\})$" implies there is some structure on this set that an automorphism should preserve. What is this structure?

Comment: @Adayah Honestly, I am not exactly sure. I am trying to figure this out myself; I suppose that we should equipp $C(\{1,...,n\})$ with whatever binary operator makes sense in this context. Perhaps function addition? Function composition?

Comment: @Adayah I added a bit more context. I believe we are endowing $C(\{1,...,n\})$ with function addition. I know that the diagonal matrices and $C(\{1,...,n\})$  are $*$-ring isomorphic: just use the mapping $C(\{1,...,n\})  \ni f \mapsto diag(f(1),....,f(n))$, where the $*$ operation on $C(\{1,...,n\})$ is $f(x)^* = \overline{f(x)}$ and the $*$ operation on the diagonal matrices is the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Even simpler, $C(\{1,\cdots,n\})$ is just $\Bbb C^n$. Thing is, $T_U(X):=U^{\ast}XU$ generally does *not* restrict to a map on the subspace of diagonal matrices, let alone act by a permutation. Cite your source?

Comment: @anon See proposition 4 on page 4: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.5219.pdf        I used slightly different notation than is used in the linked paper.

Comment: For future reference, that's the sort of thing you should provide in your question without being asked. This way if you miss out on providing context, readers can make up the difference (in this case, you did not state the implication you were trying to prove *assumed* that $T_U(\mathcal{D}_n)\subseteq\mathcal{D}_n$, and did not originally reveal $C(\{1,\cdots,n\})$ was identified with the algebra of diagonal matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal matrices $\mathcal{D}_n\subseteq\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are a $\mathbb{C}$-subalgebra isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$ with componentwise operations of addition and multiplication. Note that $\mathbb{C}^n$ may be thought of as the space of functions $\{1,\cdots,n\}\to\mathbb{C}$. In particular, a coordinate vector $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ corresponds to the function $f(i)=a_i$ and a function $f$ corresponds to the coordinate vector $(f(1),\cdots,f(n))$.

The group $S_n$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by permuting coordinates. If you think about $\mathbb{C}^n$ as the space of functions $\{1,\cdots,n\}\to\mathbb{C}$, the action is by precomposition. That is, if $f$ is such a function and $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, then the corresponding action on functions sends $f$ to $f\circ\sigma^{-1}$. This is what the author means by "every automorpism is a composition with a homeomorphism" (although I don't know why  they would refer to a humble permutation of a finite set as a "homeomorphism").

An automorphism of of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra must be a coordinate permutation (can you prove this?), so all automorphisms come from this action of $S_n$. So let's examine the following implication:

> If $T_U(X)=U^{\ast}XU$ satisfies $T_U(\mathcal{D}_n)\subset\mathcal{D}_n$ then $U\in\mathcal{G}_n$, where $\mathcal{G}_n$ is the group generated by the diagonal unitary matrices and permutation matrices.

To prove this implication, first note that $T_U$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algbera automorphism of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, so if it restricts to a map on $\mathcal{D}_n$ it is an algebra automorphism of $\mathcal{D}_n$, so it is a permutation of the diagonal entries, and such permutations are precisely $T_P$ for the corresponding permutation matrix $P$, so we conclude that $T_U=T_P$. This means $T_{P^{-1}U}$ is the identity map on $\mathcal{D}_n$, Since $U\in\mathcal{G}_n$ is equivalent to $P^{-1}U\in\mathcal{G}_n$, it suffices to prove $P^{-1}U\in\mathcal{G}_n$.

Now you need to prove that if $T_V$ acts as the identity map on $\mathcal{D}_n$, it is diagonal itself. To prove this, write $T_V(e_{ii})=e_{ii}$ for the diagonal basis matrices, e.g. $e_{11}=\mathrm{diag}(1,0,\cdots,0)$.

Comment: Just a quick question. What exactly do you mean by an algebra? I have seen this term thrown around quite a lot. Do you mean this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Associative_algebras_over_rings And so a $\Bbb{C}$-algebra would be an algebra over the complex number field?

Comment: @user193319 Yes. Except "number field" is a phrase that means something in math, and $\Bbb C$ is not a number field because it is not a finite-degree, algebraic field extension of $\Bbb Q$. (Of course you just mean the field of complex numbers, but I thought I'd point that out.)